# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on array allocation (CIDetector featuresInImage)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, augmented-reality

I am following a facial recognition app example from Pro iOS 5 Augmented Reality book. I even downloaded the source code... I ran it from there and the problem persists with his code. Here is the problem: It crashes on the assignment of an array that takes the featuresInImage of a CGImage for a CIDetector that is detecting for a face. From logging... it seems that this method is called many many many times... I am using cocos2d_chipmunk so I am using a CSScene. Note that this crash is an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4499923c)`
Help please?

```
  - (void)facialRecognitionRequest:(UIImage *)image {
//NSLog(@"Image is: %f by %f", image.size.width, image.size.height);
if (!isProcessingRequest) {
    isProcessingRequest = YES;
    //NSLog(@"Detecting Faces");
  NSArray* arr = [detector featuresInImage:[CIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]]]; // CRASHES HERE


    if ([arr count] > 0) {
        //NSLog(@"Faces found.");
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) { //< [arr count]; i++) {
            CIFaceFeature *feature = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
            double xPosition = (feature.leftEyePosition.x + feature.rightEyePosition.x+feature.mouthPosition.x)/(3*image.size.width) ;
            double yPosition = (feature.leftEyePosition.y + feature.rightEyePosition.y+feature.mouthPosition.y)/(3*image.size.height);

            double dist = sqrt(pow((feature.leftEyePosition.x - feature.rightEyePosition.x),2)+pow((feature.leftEyePosition.y - feature.rightEyePosition.y),2))/image.size.width;

            yPosition += dist;
            CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
            pumpkin.opacity = 255;
            pumpkin.scale = 5*(size.width*dist)/256.0;

            //int randomPumpkin = ((arc4random() % 10) + 5);
            [pumpkin setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pumpkin%d.png", pumpkin_count + 4]]];
            CCMoveTo *moveAction = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0 position:ccp((size.width * (xPosition)), (size.height * ((yPosition))))];
            [pumpkin runAction:moveAction];

        }
    } else {
        pumpkin.opacity = 0;

    }    


}
isProcessingRequest = NO;

  }
```

Assigning the CIDetector:

```
  - (id)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
  // ....... other stuff here        
    NSDictionary *detectorOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:CIDetectorAccuracyLow, CIDetectorAccuracy, nil];
    self.detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:detectorOptions]; // CIDetector instance named detector is my property

}
return self;
 }
```

I tried:
        CGImage *theCGImage = [image CGImage];
    NSLog(@"theCGImage: %@", theCGImage);

```
CIImage *theCIImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:theCGImage];
NSLog(@"theCIImage: %@", theCIImage);

NSArray* arr = [detector featuresInImage:theCIImage];
NSLog(@"arr: %@", arr);
```

Here are the results:

```
 2012-04-15 19:08:25.136 Ch8[981:609f] tmpCGImage: <CGImage 0x1f689c00>
 2012-04-15 19:08:25.143 Ch8[981:609f] tmpCIImage: <CIImage: 0x1f687970 extent [0 0 480 360]>
 2012-04-15 19:08:25.282 Ch8[981:609f] arr: (
"<CIFaceFeatureInternal: 0x1f58e080>"
)
```

I also tried enabling `NSZombies` but still no luck... any ideas?

Comment: Break the crashing line down into it's separate bits (i.e. `image.CGImage`, `[CIImage imagewithCGImage:` and `featuresInImage:`) and see which one causes the problem. I suspect either your image or your detector have been deallocated. Are you using ARC?

Comment: no I'm not using ARC... but ill try that

Comment: I suspect that you haven't retained your detector enough - can you add the line of code where you create it to the question?

Comment: If you have a problem in a complex statement the first thing to do when debugging is to break it down into it's constituent parts and fine the part that is causing the problem. See @deanWombourne

Comment: how would i do that do i just write if statements to see if they are non-zero then log it?

Comment: Is your detector property `retain`? And if it has a custom setter, did you make sure to actually call retain in it?

Comment: yeah:

@property (nonatomic, retain) CIDetector *detector;

Comment: @user1260708 - The problem isn't that they're `nil` - the problem is that you have a pointer to an object that doesn't exist anymore. Testing for `nil` will do nothing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to the comment (not the entire question, presented as answer just for the formatting):
"how would i do that do i just write if statements to see if they are non-zero then log it?"

Instead of:

```
  NSArray* arr = [detector featuresInImage:[CIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]]];
```

break it up into three statements:

```
CGImage *theCGImage = [image CGImage];
NSLog(@"theCGImage: %@", theCGImage);

CIImage *theCIImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:theCGImage];
NSLog(@"theCIImage: %@", theCIImage);

NSArray* arr = [detector featuresInImage:theCIImage];
NSLog(@"arr: %@", arr);
```

So that the offending statement can be found. This is a general debugging technique and not a bad way to write the code in any case.

The `NSLog` statements are not really necessary, a breakpoint on the first statement and then single step through.

For crashes due to premature releases use `NSZombies`. It can be enabled in Xcode under "Edit Scheme, tab: "Diagnostics", be sure to turn it off when running on the device.

[image]

Comment: Great, that has narrowed things down. Potentially I would look at `detector` and its method: `featuresInImage`. Note that accessing a released object is not predictable. Turn on NSZombies, that should help you find the problem. Do insure that `detector` is properly retained. If at all possible use ARC.

Comment: no... still deosnt work ;( same crash ... lemme do some more stuff then get back to u

Answer (score 0):

Check if an Exception Breakpoint is added.
In my case, an exception was thrown inside the features function call and the breakpoint trying to catch the exception caused the crash. By removing the Exception Breakpoint from the Breakpoint list, the crash went away.